# What is the best way to test a node.js web server for security issues?

Tags: node.js, security, testing

How could we test our `node.js` webserver for security issues?

Comment: What you need is a penetration tester not a hacker.

Comment: You don't need a "hacker". What you need is called a [pen tester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_test)

Comment: I cannot ask question any more, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I would check active node.js version vs https://nodejs.org/ (front page), update node.js if necessary, and use `npm audit` to check all nested npm dependencies including devDependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are good software like Acunetix which can do a pretty well job. Basically it tests common hacking technics like sql injection and cross scripting, then generating a report of the issues if there are any. But is quite expensive.